# How to get a number from a specific index?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi every one I'm working on a project, I found myself in a need to get a number from a string in a specific index for example : I've this id and I must get both numbers (taking into account that a number can contain 1 or more digitals ex : 1 or 12 )

id = stock_stockbundle_facturefounisseur_ligneffm_1_ligneff_1_idarticle

As you can notice the id contains the number 1 in two different parts, so I need both numbers inside this string !
I thought about using substring but if the first number contains more than one digits , I could miss the second number

if someone has an idea, 
thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: So what output do you want, exactly? `"11"`, `[1,1]`, `["1","1"]`, something else entirely? And what do you mean by '*a specific index*'?

Comment: Use regular expressions to get out the numbers into an array.

Comment: if its possible , each number in a uniq variable, number1, number2

Comment: thanks for help but I'm just a beginner, and I don't know to work with RegEx,

Comment: tnx thomas, if its possible to -just- get the two numbers (forgetting the index), its very useful

Comment: There are many ways to do retrieve the number(s), but you need to specify *what you want*. Otherwise you'll get lots of suggestions, most of which will be useless to you, and we all spend a lot of time trying to refine the eventual solutions instead of building the solution to meet your need.

Comment: that is my need : get numbers from different parts of a string and put each one of them in a variable! hopefully its clear!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
var id='stock_stockbundle_facturefounisseur_ligneffm_10_ligneff_2_idarticle';
var pattern=/\d+/g;
var res = id.match(pattern);
alert(res[0]); //will be 10
alert(res[1]); //will be 2
```

Both numbers are stored in the array `res`

If you don't care about the split between the 2 numbers (so you would just need '102'):

```
var id='stock_stockbundle_facturefounisseur_ligneffm_10_ligneff_2_idarticle';
var res = id.replace(/\D+/g,'');
alert(res); //will be 102
```

Comment: very helpful thanks but, what if the id= stock_stockbundle_facturefounisseur_ligneffm_10_ligneff_2_idarticle, in this case, we'll have :
alert(res[0]); //will be 1
alert(res[1]); //will be 0
alert(res[2]); //will be 2
or 
alert(res[0]); //will be 10
alert(res[1]); //will be 2 ????

Comment: res[0] will be 10, while res[1] will be 2 ! It will split on any non-numeric character !

Comment: thank you so much, veru helpful and thats what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = "stock_stockbundle_facturefounisseur_ligneffm_1_ligne4ff_1_idarticle";
var idArrayCheck = id.split("");
var idNumbers = [];

inArray(idArrayCheck);

function inArray(array) {
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == 1 || array[i] == 2 || array[i] == 3 || array[i] == 4 || array[i] == 5 || array[i] == 6 || array[i] == 7 || array[i] == 8 || array[i] == 9 || array[i] == 0) {
                idNumbers.push(array[i]);
            }
        }
    }

idNumbers = idNumbers.join("");

alert(idNumbers);
```

idNumbers will be a string equal to "141"

Comment: I don't think this solution is what the questioner is looking for. I also think this code is rather inefficient (and you need to add zero to be able to find '10').

Comment: I agree this is probably inefficient and kind of ugly actually.  But it works just fine and is pretty simple.  I think it's exactly what the poster is looking for, though.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach:

```js
function retrieveNumberMatches(haystack) {
  return haystack.match(/\d+/g);
}

var numbers = retrieveNumberMatches("stock_stockbundle_facturefounisseur_ligneffm_1_ligneff_1_idarticle");


numbers.forEach(function(n, i) {
  console.log('Number ' + i + ': ' + n);
});
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).